# ADO vs ADO.NET: when to use each?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, ado.net, ado

I realize this is somewhat of an opinion question but I'd like to hear some people's insights.

I'm working in VBA and VB.NET and currently use ADO to INSERT, UPDATE, and SELECT records in a PostgreSQL database using Excel as the user interface. ADO works great but it seems MS pushes ADO.NET as being the better tool, but my problem with it is that I'd have to create almost the entire PostgreSQL database as an in-memory dataset which I believe is unneeded because then I'm just copying entirely what's already on the server plus it's a lot to hold in memory.

That said, what is everyone's thoughts on ADO vs ADO.NET given the situation of having to recreate nearly the entire database in memory for ADO.NET to do what ADO currently does? Is ADO still a relevant solution in some cases nowadays? Is there another alternative tech that someone would recommend?

Comment: Off topic for SO really, but there's no requirement in ADO.NET to "recreate nearly the entire database in memory".  Why do you think that?

Comment: @TimWilliams Correct, I realize that but in my specific case there are a very wide number of tables and views that users need to be able to read/write and all of them need to be present in the dataset if I'm using ADO.NET, I believe. I'm definitely less experienced with ADO.NET so I could be missing something but it seems to me that everything that the developer wants the users to be able to read/write to needs to be present in the dataset. Does that make sense?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry for the dumb question, Tim.  After playing with ADO.NET more I see that I misunderstood...alot...about how it works.  Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Use the tech that plays well with the language you're using.

The ADODB library works very well with [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6) and [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), so use it when you write code in VBA, which predates .NET by quite a number of years.

ADO.NET is the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) equivalent; use it when you write in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) or [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), simple as that.

ADO is only as relevant as VBA is *for your situation*, and using ADO.NET in VBA sounds like quite a lot of useless gymnastics.

"Recreating the entire database in memory" sounds very much like an X-Y problem, I very much doubt that's really what you want to achieve - perhaps you meant to refer to Object/Relational Mappers (ORM's), like [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework), or even more dated tech (although still post-ADO.NET), like [linq-to-sql](/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql)? Either way, an ORM makes an abstraction over the data access technology it's using, so if you want to implement one in VBA over ADODB, go for it! And if you want to reinvent the wheel and implement one in VB.NET over ADO.NET, ..it could be fun. But I doubt that's what you want to do.

Microsoft is "pushing" ADO.NET as a "better tool" because .NET is current and it's being actively maintained and it's constantly evolving, ..and not VBA - at least as far as I know. Now watch the dates of what you read online, because Microsoft was "pushing" Linq-to-SQL as a "better tool" than ADO.NET, and then later started "pushing" Entity Framework as a "better tool" than Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I realized after playing with ADO.NET more that I definitely did not understand it correctly when I said I was going to have to recreate the entire database in memory.  Sorry for the dumb question, but I appreciate your patient and informative answer.